# Finding the n-th derivative of a rational function

Tags: derivatives, rational-functions

Given $$f : \left(\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right) \to \mathbb{R} \ \ \ \ \ \ 
 \ \ \ \ f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$$

I am trying to find an expression for $f^{n}(x)$ and prove it by induction afterwards.

I tried first splitting into partial fractions but it got messy, not sure if that's the right approach.

Comment: Why is partial fractions messy? It's for sure the simplest way

Comment: Thanks for your effort to increase the size of the parentheses around the given interval.  A really nice way to do so, that auto-adjusts the parentheses to match the size of what they enclose, is to use, e.g., in this case,`$f : \left(\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right) \to \mathbb{R}$`, as I did in my edit to your post.  The same holds true for brackets, etc. E.g. `$\left[ \frac 12\right]^2$` will render as $\left[ \frac 12\right]^2$

Comment: alternatively consider $(-1/2,1/2)$, what seems easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using partial fractions you should get 
$$f(x)=A(x-a)^{-1}+B(x-b)^{-1}$$

Then $n$th derivative of $(x-c)^{-1}$ is easy to calculate.

---

Note: $$\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x+\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}}\right)$$

Comment: Is this then correct? $\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\frac1{1-x-x^2}=(-1)^n n!\left(\frac{1}{(x-a)^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{(x-b)^{n+1}}\right)$

Comment: Doesn't this answer say just what the original poster already knew?

Comment: @9Sp : That is correct, except that of course the $A$ and $B$ in the numerators need to be there. However, I suspect you can simplify the expression a lot after putting it in that form.

Comment: @9Sp $$ \frac{1}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{x+\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{x-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}}$$ You are missing somee coefficients in the  numerator, and need to imput the $a,b$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

$$
1-x-x^2 = -\left(x-\frac{-1+\sqrt 5} 2\right)\left(x-\frac{-1-\sqrt5} 2\right) = \left( \frac{-1+\sqrt 5} 2 - x \right) \left( \frac{1+\sqrt 5} 2 + x \right)
$$
$$
\frac A {\frac{-1+\sqrt 5} 2 - x} + \frac B {\frac{1+\sqrt5} 2 + x} = \frac 1{\left( \frac{-1+\sqrt 5} 2 - x \right) \left( \frac{1+\sqrt 5} 2 + x \right)}
$$
$$
A\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5} 2 + x \right) + B\left( \frac{-1+\sqrt 5} 2 - x \right) = 0x + 1
$$
So $A-B=0$ and $(A+B) \left( \dfrac{\sqrt 5} 2 \right) = 1.$ Hence $A=B=\dfrac 1 {\sqrt 5}.$